# A debate over the limit of $ \frac{f(x + a h) - f(x + b h)}{h} $ as $ h $ approaches $ 0 $.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

This may seem like an easy question, but a few of us are having a debate over it. We are looking at the following limit below, where $ f $ is a real-valued function on an open subset $ U $ of $ \mathbb{R} $ that is differentiable at the point $ x_{0} $, and where $ a $ and $ b $ are in $ \mathbb{R} $:
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(x + a h) - f(x + b h)}{h}.
$$

My friend thinks that this is equal to $ f'(x_{0}) $, but I don’t see how to prove that this is true.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Certainly the limit would not be equal to $f'(x_0)$ if $a=b=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to prove your friend wrong is to apply this to a function that we really understand, like $f(x) = x$. We'll do it at $x_0 = 1$. Then you are calculating

$$ \frac{f(1 + ah) - f(1 + bh)}{h} = \frac{1 + ah - 1 - bh}{h} = (a - b).$$

This is not $1$ and depends critically on $a$ and $b$ (exactly like derivatives do not).

More generally, we can write (but where I omit all limit signs)
$$ \begin{align}
\frac{f(x_0 + ah) - f(x_0 + bh)}{h} &= \frac{f(x_0 + ah) - f(x_0)}{h} - \frac{f(x_0 + bh) - f(x_0)}{h} \\
&\to af'(x_0) - bf'(x_0) = (a-b)f'(x_0).
\end{align}$$

Comment: but how do we know a and b can both be 1, it just says that a and b are in R

Comment: This also gives a hint of what the limit is in general. $a - b = (a-b)\cdot 1 = (a-b)f'(x_0)$

Comment: Indeed, the limit should be $a - b$ times the correct derivative.

Comment: so f'(x_0)(a-b) right? That's what I originally thought

Comment: In the new edit, this is not just for f(x) = x right, this is in a general sense

Comment: Yes. This holds for all differentiable $f$.

Comment: Shouldn't it say $(a-b)f'(x_0)$ at the end? You have b-a instead of a-b.

Comment: @columbus8myhw yes- that's right. Thank you